# How to check if field exist along with the other 'and' condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to check if `category 1 and 2` is true and also if the `selected category` exists.
Am I doing this correctly?

```
{user.choices?.category1 && user.choices?.category2 == true && user.choices?.selectedCategory ? (
                  <div>
                    //some codes here
                 </div>
                ) : (
                  <div></div>
                )}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'correct'?

Comment: Can you explain more what you are checking categories 1 and 2 for? Are they bools?

Comment: @pilchard what I meant was the boolean true, sorry

Comment: @RyanMillares yes, they are booleans 'true'

Comment: lgtm. however, you should run your own test to figure out the edge cases as other comments are pointing out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try checking if the category is null. Also, if categories 1 and 2 are supposed to be bools, then:

```
{
((user.choices?.category1 && user.choices?.category2) == true && user.choices?.selectedCategory != null) ? (
              <div>
                //some codes here
             </div>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )
}
```

I'm still slightly confused though as to what you are checking with the other two categories

Comment: I was checking if category 1 and 2 is true

Answer (score -1):

`Categry2 == true` isn't needed. And yes you're doing it correctly.

```
{
    user.choices?.category1 &&
    user.choices?.category2 &&
    user.choices?.selectedCategory ? (
        <div>//some codes here</div>
    ) : (
        <div></div>
    );
}
```